# Setting external html file to a TemplateRef in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HighlightDirective, EditTmpl],
    template: '<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="currentTplRef"></template>'//require('./nav-menu.html')
})

export class NavMenu implements OnInit {
    @Input() templ: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild('displayTmpl') displayTmpl : TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild('editTmpl') editTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;    
    childView: EmbeddedViewRef<any>;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.childView = this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templ);
    }    
}
```

I have two external html files in the same folder as this ts file and the code inside looks like this (this html file is called displayTmpl):

```
<template #displayTmpl>
    <table>...</table>
</template>
```

How can I load this html view dinamically? I want to set currentTplRef to one of my html files.

Comment: In the following [link](https://www.dev6.com/Modal-Templates-in-Angular2-Part-3) there is a solution but if you ask me, I think it's better to use separate components and pass the needed data to it using a input, like [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child).